# How to use phpjs mail function

Tags: email, phpjs

how to implement phpjs mail function?

This is a little confusing to explain, so bear with me here...

Here my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mail.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#target" ).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $(this).data('email');
        var to = $( "input[name=myEmail]" ).val();
        var subject = $( "input[name=mySubject]" ).val();
        var message = $( "textarea[name=myMessage]" ).val();
        var headers = 'From: '+email;
        var test = mail(to, subject, message, headers);
        console.log(test);
    });
});
</script>
<form id="target" method="post" data-email="admin@website.com">
Email<br />
   <input type="TEXT" name="myEmail"  value=""/><br />
Subject<br />
   <input type="TEXT" name="mySubject"  value=""/><br />
Message<br />
<textarea name="myMessage"></textarea>
   <input type="SUBMIT" value="Send">

</form>
```

But the result is always false.
What wrong?

Comment: Surely there's a more helpful error message than just a `false` result from the call to `mail()`.  What does that `mail()` function *actually* do?  How does it attempt to send an email?  Does it make an AJAX call to a PHP server-side resource?  What is the response from that resource?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://phpjs.org/functions/mail/) was implemented primarily as a thought experiment. See the note, "Currently only works if the SSJS SendMail method is available" (SendMail was a very early SSJS constructor). Some of phpjs may be used exclusively in a server-side JavaScript environment. We'd be open to pull requests which support Node.js as that seems to have perhaps [become its own standard](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5132) or perhaps which support other privileged environments (e.g., like a Thunderbird extension or perhaps if more people start using it and if Firefox has or adds adequate mail interfaces, my [AsYouWish](https://github.com/brettz9/asyouwish/) add-on which allows websites to make privileged requests of the browser upon user permission).

In other words, if you want client-side mail, for now you'll probably need to do it by interacting with your server (and then, hopefully securely).